# How do I fill a SystemVerilog Queue variable?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, hdl

```
module queues;
int a[$];

int i = 100;

initial begin
    foreach(a[i]) a[i] = i;
    foreach(a[i]) $display("\tValue of a[%0d]=%0d",i,a[i]);
end
endmodule
```

I have my unbounded queue '`a`'. I have to fill > 150 locations with random data. I have to use (push/pop/positional) constructs as well. I am trying to fill some of the positions using for/foreach loop, but it's not working.

> Error msg: XXXX: I don't know how to handle expr_type=9 here error:
> Code generation had 1 error(s).

Where am I wrong? And what do you suggest to do in this problem statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I run your code on my simulators, I don't get any error message.  But, I also don't see any of the display messages either.  That is expected because neither of your `foreach` loops executes.  Since the queue is empty, the 1st `foreach` loop has nothing to loop over.  Therefore, nothing is added to the queue.  Similarly for the 2nd `foreach`.

You can use a `for` loop to add to the queue:

```
module queues;

int a[$];

initial begin
    for (int i=0; i<100; i++) a.push_back(i);
    foreach(a[i]) $display("\tValue of a[%0d]=%0d",i , a[i]);
end
endmodule
```

This prints:

```
Value of a[0]=0
Value of a[1]=1
Value of a[2]=2
Value of a[3]=3
Value of a[4]=4
Value of a[5]=5
```

etc.

If you really want random data (as you mentioned), you could use something like `$urandom`:

```
for (int i=0; i<100; i++) a.push_back($urandom);
```